# IntelliJ automatically imports something I don't need imported

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an enum class with a ton of enums, which I like to address as

```
Enumclass.argument1
Enumclass.argument2
Enumclass.argument3
```

I had a ton of such references in a file, however IntelliJ decided to put import statements at the top:

```
import static com.abc.util.Enumclass.argument1;
import static com.abc.util.Enumclass.argument2;
import static com.abc.util.Enumclass.argument3;
```

and change the references to just

```
argument1
argument2
argument3
```

I want to disable this, and also revert what it did. I've been digging around but I just can't find where to do this! I'm on MAC OSX, IJ 12.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Hit Alt+Enter on the enum to bring up the options menu, and the first item should say *Expand static import to Enumclass.argument1*. Press Enter, then chose to do it for all occurrences of that argument1.